# I need to calculate a value running down over time according to another value in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In a BigQuery table, I need to refer to the previous value from the same column to calculate the new value for that column like this:

| Timestamp | Liters per Minute | Liters remaining |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-15 08:50 UTC | 5 | 1000 |
| 2022-08-15 08:51 UTC | 4 | 1000 - (avg(5, 4) = 4.5) = 995.5 |
| 2022-08-15 08:51 UTC | 6 | 995.5 - (avg(4, 6) = 5) = 990.5 |
| 2022-08-15 08:51 UTC | 6 | 990.5 - (avg(6, 6) = 6) = 984.5 |

Sometimes the 'Liters remaining' will come from outside, so I actually have used coalesce to choose either this external actual value if it exists, or the previous value in time for this column if it doesn't:

liters remaining estimated = `coalesce(Liters remaining actual, lag(liters remaining estimated) - liters per minute)`

but I can't refer to 'self' (liters remaining estimated) in the calculation (I think!)

| Timestamp | Liters per Minute | Liters remaining actual | Liters remaining estimated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-15 08:50 UTC | 5 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 2022-08-15 08:51 UTC | 4 |  | 1000 - (avg(5, 4) = 4.5) = 995.5 |
| 2022-08-15 08:51 UTC | 6 |  | 995.5 - (avg(4, 6) = 5) = 990.5 |
| 2022-08-15 08:51 UTC | 6 |  | 990.5 - (avg(6, 6) = 6) = 984.5 |
| 2022-08-15 08:51 UTC | 6 | 986 | 986 |
| 2022-08-15 08:51 UTC | 3 |  | 986 - (avg(6, 3) = 4.5) 981.5 |

I'm not sure how to split this up or if there is some magic bq sql I'm about to learn :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consier below query. I've slightly modified your **liters remaining** logic like below and applied kind of **cumulative sum** analytic function to generate expected output.

- 1000 - SUM(-5, 5) /2 = 1000
- 1000 - SUM(5, 4) / 2 = 995.5
- 1000 - SUM(5, 4, 4, 6) / 2 = 990.5
- 1000 - SUM(5, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6) / 2 = 984.5

**actual_liters** column is used to partition a table whenever new actual liters is given.

```sql
WITH partitioned AS (
  SELECT *,
         LAST_VALUE(Liters_remaining_actual IGNORE NULLS) OVER w AS actual_liters,
         IF(Liters_remaining_actual IS NULL, 
            LAG(Liters_per_Minute) OVER w,  -1 * Liters_per_Minute
         ) AS pre_liters_per_minute,
    FROM sample_table
  WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY Timestamp)
)
SELECT *,
       actual_liters - SUM(Liters_per_Minute + pre_liters_per_minute) OVER w / 2 AS Liters_remaining_estimated
  FROM partitioned
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY actual_liters ORDER BY Timestamp)
 ORDER BY Timestamp;
```

[image]

Comment: This worked! Thank you - I didn't know how to do that but I'd seen it in the docs and not thought it would be what I needed :)